# Why does MySQL expect a parameter in this case

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to get an email from a customer table and send message to that email. I am getting this error

> "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be"

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
       $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "hname", "passs", "dbname");

       $getusers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer");
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       sendMail($row['email']);
       }
       mysql_free_result($result);
       function sendMail($to){
       $subject = 'the subject';
       $message = 'hello';
       $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
       }
?>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be

Comment: Also you get this warning by using empty `$result` in `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Answer (score 5):

You are making a `myslqi` connection but then using `mysql_*` (no `i`) functions.  You should use all `mysqli`.

Comment: (This *was* a reasonable answer. Once. Then the code in the question changed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

TO

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getusers)) {
```